# How to create a custom POJO for Apache Flink

Tags: json, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pojo

I'm using Flink to process some JSON-format data coming from some Data Source.

For now, my process is quite simple: extract each element from the JSON-format data and print them into log file.

Here is my piece of code:

```
// create proper deserializer to deserializer the JSON-format data into ObjectNode
PravegaDeserializationSchema<ObjectNode> adapter = new PravegaDeserializationSchema<>(ObjectNode.class, new JavaSerializer<>());
// create connector to receive data from Pravega
FlinkPravegaReader<ObjectNode> source = FlinkPravegaReader.<ObjectNode>builder()
    .withPravegaConfig(pravegaConfig)
    .forStream(stream)
    .withDeserializationSchema(adapter)
    .build();
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<ObjectNode> dataStream = env.addSource(source).name("Pravega Stream");
dataStream.???.print();
```

Saying that the data coming from Pravega is like this: `{"name":"titi", "age":18}`

As I said, for now I simply need to extract `name` and `age` and print them.

So how could I do this?

As my understanding, I need to make some customized codes at `???`. I might need to create a custom POJO class which contains `ObjectNode`. But I don't know how. I've read the official doc of Flink and also tried to google about how to create a custom POJO for Flink but I can't still figure out clearly.

Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't You simply use something more meaningful instead of `JavaSerializer`? Perhaps something from [here](https://github.com/pravega/pravega-serializer).

You could then create a POJO with the fields you want to use and simply deserialize JSON data to Your POJO instead of `ObjectNode`

Also, if there is some specific reason that You need to have `ObjectNode` on deserialization then You can simply do something like :

```
//I assume You have created the class named MyPojo
dataStream.map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, MyPojo>() {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            @Override
            public MyPojo map(final ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
                mapper.readValue(value.asText(), MyPojo.class)
            }
})
```

Comment: Could you please show me an example about `You could then create a POJO with the fields you want to use and simply deserialize JSON data to Your POJO`?

Comment: @yves For a complete example (for Kafka, but the interfaces are pretty much the same), see https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/playgrounds/ops/clickcount/records/ClickEventDeserializationSchema.java.